# using sed to lazy find and replace across multiple lines

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to remove blocks of html code from a file. The block to be remove appears multiple times in the file and also spans multiple lines. Also of notes the block has different content in it but has clear start and end delineations.

I have tried a number of approaches to get this to work and am running into issues getting laziness working in `sed` and matching across lines.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
good stuff a
good stuff same line START
bad stuff 1.0
bad stuff 1.1
END
good stuff b
good stuff b
good stuff same line START bad stuff 2.0
bad stuff 2.0
END
good stuff c
```

Becomes:

```
good stuff a
good stuff same line
good stuff b
good stuff b
good stuff same line
good stuff c
```

Here are some approaches I have tried so far.

`sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/START.*END//mg;p;}' < test > test2`  Gets across lines to work.

`sed -n 's/START[^END]*END//g' < test > test2` Only negates E or N or D.

`sed -n 's/START.*?END//g' < test > test2` Doesn't behave with laziness.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `sed` might be to hard to do that. Two `sed`s make it trivial:

`sed 's/START/\nSTART\n/g' | sed '/START/,/END/d'`

Comment: this doesn't seem to add newlines in my terminal

Comment: It works for me exactly as you requested in your question. Goal is not to add newlines, but to move START to a separate line which will be then removed by range delete.

Comment: The portable way to get sed to understand newlines is to hard-code them as a backslash followed by carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

sed is not great for dealing with multi-line input.
Use awk instead.
You want to match a line for it's regular expression, and turn off printing if it's the beginning of your 'bad' block. Here's an example for your file:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN    { pr = 1; }
/^START/  { pr = 0; }
          { if (pr) print; }
/^END/    { pr = 1; }
' < yourfile
good stuff a
good stuff b
good stuff b
good stuff c
```

Comment: This chews up the whole line and thus doesn't meet the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ sed '/START/,/END/d' file.txt
good stuff a
good stuff b
good stuff b
good stuff c
```

Read more about `ranges` [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/START/!b;:a;/END/bb;$!{N;ba};:b;s/START.*END//' file
```

Comment: Deals well with placement of START and END within a line, and multiple occurances.

Answer (score 0):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else use awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/START.*|.*END/,""){f=!f;if(NF)print;next} !f' file
good stuff a
good stuff same line
good stuff b
good stuff b
good stuff same line
good stuff c
```

Comment: Solves this particular problem, but doesn't use sed and doesn't work for certain edge cases (see potong's solution).

Comment: Clearly it doesn't use sed as this is not an appropriate job for sed. Which edge cases are you referring to?